# How to make an analog of COUNT(from another table) when requesting SELECT after WHERE

Tags: mysql

I need a query that, when the conditions are met, takes into account the number of occurrences of a certain record in COUNT(*).

My non-working solution:

```
SELECT t.name, t.tovar_id, p.path FROM `tovars` t, `tovarPicture` p WHERE t.nomGroup = :group AND p.tovar_id = t.tovar_id AND p.tovarPicture_id IS NULL AND COUNT(SELECT * FROM knotConnections WHERE tovar_id = t.tovar_id) = 0
```

Comment: If the count must always be zero (ie, there are no matching records in the other table) then you could use NOT EXISTS or an anti-join.  If you need more flexibility - you want the count to be a specific non-zero number - then you could do an inner join, COUNT and use a HAVING clause.

Comment: the value can be any, you need it to be calculated using COUNT() and as a result it gives only a value equal to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the count must always be zero (ie, there are no matching records in the other table) then you could use NOT EXISTS or an anti-join:

```sql
SELECT t.name, t.tovar_id, p.path
FROM `tovars` t
INNER JOIN`tovarPicture` p ON t.tovar_id = p.tovar_id
LEFT JOIN knotConnections ON t.tovar_id = knotConnections.tovar_id
WHERE t.nomGroup = :group
AND p.tovarPicture_id IS NULL
AND knotConnections.tovar_id IS NULL
```

If you need more flexibility - you want the count to be a specific number - then you could use COUNT in a HAVING clause:

```sql
SELECT t.name, t.tovar_id, p.path
FROM `tovars` t
INNER JOIN`tovarPicture` p ON t.tovar_id = p.tovar_id
LEFT JOIN knotConnections ON t.tovar_id = knotConnections.tovar_id
WHERE t.nomGroup = :group
AND p.tovarPicture_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.name, t.tovar_id, p.path
HAVING COUNT(knotConnections.tovar_id) = :yourNumberHere
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob Eyre's answer shows the usual ways of doing this, but what you had was close to working, you just need to change

```
COUNT(SELECT *
```

to

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
```

When you want to use the value of a subquery it in an expression, you just have to enclose it in parens (and make sure it is returning the single value you want, not more than one value or more than one row).